# Creating a non trivial view of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

## TL;DR:

I am looking for a way to get a non trivial, and in particular non contigous, view of a numpy `ndarray`.

E.g., given a 1D ndarray, `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])`, is there a way to get a non trivial **view** of it, e.g. `np.array([2, 4, 3, 1])`?

## Longer Version

The context of the question is the following: I have a 4D ndarray of shape `(U, V, S, T)` which I would like to reshape to a 2D ndarray of shape `(U*S, V*T)`in a non-trivial way, i.e. a simple `np.reshape()`does not do the trick as I have a more complex indexing scheme in mind, in which the reshaped array will not be contigous in memory. The arrays in my case are rather large and I would like to get a view and not a copy of the array.

### Example

Given an array `x(u, v, s, t)`of shape `(2, 2, 2, 2)`:

```
x = np.array([[[[1, 1], [1, 1]],[[2, 2], [2, 2]]],
              [[[3, 3], [3, 3]], [[4, 4], [4, 4]]]])
```

I would like to get the **view** `z(a, b)` of the array:

```
np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
          [1, 1, 2, 2],
          [3, 3, 4, 4],
          [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

This corresponds to a indexing scheme of `a = u * S + s` and `b = v * T + t`, where in this case `S = 2 = T`.

### What I have tried

1. Various approaches using `np.reshape` or even `as_strided`. Doing standard reshaping will not change the order of elements as they appear in the memory. I tried playing around with `order='F'` and transposing a bit but had no idea which gave me the correct result.
2. Since I know the indexing scheme, I tried to operate on the flattened view of the array using `np.ravel()`. My idea was to create an array of indices follwing the desired indexing scheme and apply it to the flattened array view, but unfortunately, fancy/advanced indexing gives a copy of the array, not a view.

## Question

Is there any way to achieve the indexing view that I'm looking for?

In principle, I think this should be possible, as for example `ndarray.sort()` performs an in place non-trivial indexing of the array. On the other hand, this is probably implemented in C/C++, so it might even not be possible in pure Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review the basics of an array - it has a flat data buffer, a `shape`, `strides`, and `dtype`. Those three attributes are used to `view` the elements of the data buffer in a particular way, whether it is a simple 1d sequence, 2d or higher dimensions.

A true `view` than use the same data buffer, but applies different shape, strides or dtype to it.

To get `[2, 4, 3, 1]` from `[1,2,3,4]` requires starting at `2`, jumping forward 2, then skipping back to 1 and forward 2.  That's not a regular pattern that can be represented by `strides`.

`arr[1::2]` gives the [2,4], and `arr[0::2]` gives the `[1,3]`.

`(U, V, S, T)` to `(U*S, V*T)` requires a transpose to `(U, S, V, T)`, followed by a reshape

```
arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(U*S, V*T)
```

That will require a copy, no way around that.

```
In [227]: arr = np.arange(2*3*4*5).reshape(2,3,4,5)
In [230]: arr1 = arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2*4, 3*5)
In [231]: arr1.shape
Out[231]: (8, 15)
In [232]: arr1
Out[232]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  40,  41,  42,
         43,  44],
       [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  45,  46,  47,
         48,  49],
       ....)
```

Or with your `x`

```
In [234]: x1 = x.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
In [235]: x1
Out[235]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Notice that the elements are in a different order:

```
In [254]: x.ravel()
Out[254]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
In [255]: x1.ravel()
Out[255]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```

`ndarray.sort` is in-place and changes the order of bytes in the data buffer.  It is operating at a low level that we don't have access to.  It isn't a `view` of the original array.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get that. I thought maybe there was a possibility to create an indexing scheme with non constant strides...